# Probability of the outcome of this simple card game

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, card-games

I have a deck of $N$ cards. $n$ of the cards are red circles and $N-n$ cards are blue circles. I also have an unlimited supply of red square and blue square cards. I play the following game and want to know the probability distribution of the outcome:

- Repeat the following process until no circle card left:
- Pick one of the circle cards from the deck at random and replace it with a square card of the same color (let's call this color $c$). Then pick another card from the deck (it could be a circle or square card of any color) at random and replace it with another square card of color $c$.

Note that in each repeated step of the above process, the second replaced card could possibly be the same as the first square card of that step.

Every time you repeat this process, you replace one or two of the circle cards with square cards. In the end, we will have $N$ square cards. I want to know the probability $P(n'|n)$ of having $n'$ red squares and $N-n'$ blue squares at the end, given $n$ initial red circles.

What do I want:

- Ideally $P(n'|n)$.
- If that's not easy, a large $N$ approximation could be equally helpful.
- Alternatively, finding the mean and the variance of $n'$ would be equally helpful. I'm guessing the mean of $n'$ is $n$.
- The mean and variance of $n'$ for large $N$ would also be good enough if nothing else works.

**Update 1**: Numerically, it looks like $\left\langle n'\right\rangle = n$, and for large $N$, $\text{var}(n') \approx\frac{3n(N-n)}{4N}$.

**Update 2**: antkam's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3351149/491395) gives a beautiful symmetry proof for $\left\langle n'\right\rangle = n$. Now, all I need is:

> Prove $\text{var}(n') \approx\frac{3n(N-n)}{4N}$ for large N.

**Update 3**: Some more numerical results that may help to find a proof: as in antkam's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3351149/491395), we can define the variable $X_i\in\{0,1,2\}$ to be the number of square cards resulted from the $i$'th circle card. $n'$ can be written as
$$n'=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$$
We can write the Var($n'$) as
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(n') &= \left\langle\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^2\right\rangle - \left\langle\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right\rangle^2\\
&=n\left(\text{Var}(X_1)+(n-1)\text{Cov}(X_1,X_2)\right)
\end{align}
$$
Numerically, I have found (**Edit**: Now both of these partial results are proven in joriki's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3681854/491395) below):

- $\text{Var}(X_1) = 3/4$
- Probabilities are $P(X=0) = P(X=2) = 3/8$ and $P(X=1)=1/4$.

Observations:

- The equality of $P(X=0) = P(X=2)$ can be justfied through the following observation: For $\sum_{i=1}^N X_i = N$ to be satisfied, the number of $X_i=0$ should be exactly the same as the number of $X_j=2$.
- For $\text{Var}(n')$ to be $\frac{3n(N-n)}{4N}$, the value of $\text{Cov}(X_1,X_2)$ should be $-\frac{3}{4N}$ to first order in $1/N$.

Comment: Interesting problem!  Just to make sure I understand, the $2$nd pick cannot be the new square card that replaced the $1$st pick, correct?  In other words, your procedure is equivalent to the following: pick a random circle card, then pick another random card (either shape), and replace both cards with two square cards of color $c$.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @antkam the second pick can be any card including the new square card

Comment: @stochastic my previous answer had a flaw. see my updated answer, showing $E[n'] = n$.

Comment: @antkam $E[n']$ is always $n$. See my answer below.

Comment: @mathworker21 - I didnt ask the question :) and I never doubted that $E[n']=n$, although I didn't find a proof as quickly as you did.  Anyway you might be interested in my alternate proof, based on symmetry.

Comment: What does $\left\langle \right\rangle$ mean? Is that expected value?

Comment: @VVejalla yes, it is the expected value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sketch of the proof for $\text{Var}(n') \approx \frac{3n(N-n)}{4(N-1)}$ at large $N$**:

As in [antkam's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3351149/491395), we can define the variable $X_i\in\{0,1,2\}$ to be the number of square cards resulted from the $i$'th circle card. $n'$ can be written as
$$n'=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$$
We can write the Var($n'$) as
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(n') &= \left\langle\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^2\right\rangle - \left\langle\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right\rangle^2\\
&=n\left(\text{Var}(X_1)+(n-1)\text{Cov}(X_1,X_2)\right)
\end{align}
$$
Where we have used the fact that $\text{Var}(X_i)$ is the same for all $i$s and $\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)$ is the same for all $i\neq j$ by symmetry.

[Joriki's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3681854/491395) proved that $\text{Var}(X_i) = 3/4$. All is left to do is to prove that $\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j) = -\frac1{N-1} \text{Var}(X_i)$, and then we will have
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(n') &=n\text{Var}(X_1)\left(1-\frac{n-1}{N-1}\right) = \frac34\frac{n(N-n)}{N-1}.
\end{align}
$$
To do this, let us first define the variables $\delta X_i \equiv X_i - \langle X_i\rangle $. The $\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)$ can be written in terms of $\delta X_i$s as (forgive the sloppy notation)
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j) &= \int\int \delta X_i \delta X_j P(\delta X_i,\delta X_j) d\delta X_i d\delta X_j\\
&=\int\int \delta X_i \delta X_j P(\delta X_i|\delta X_j) P(\delta X_j) d\delta X_i d\delta X_j\\
&=\int\delta X_j\underbrace{\left(\int \delta X_i P(\delta X_i|\delta X_j)d\delta X_i \right)}_{\langle \delta X_i|\delta X_j\rangle}  P(\delta X_j) d\delta X_j\\
\end{align}
$$
Note that since $\sum_i \delta X_i = 0$, by symmetry the expected value of $\delta X_i$ given $\delta X_j$ should be $-\frac{1}{N-1} \delta X_j$:
$$
\langle \delta X_i|\delta X_j\rangle=-\frac{1}{N-1} \delta X_j
$$
So we have:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j) &= \int\delta X_j\langle \delta X_i|\delta X_j\rangle  P(\delta X_j) d\delta X_j\\
&= -\frac1{N-1}\int\left(\delta X_j\right)^2  P(\delta X_j) d\delta X_j\\
&= -\frac1{N-1}\text{Var}(\delta X_j).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: That's great! So actually this is quite a general result: When the sum of $N$ exchangeable but dependent variables is constant, the variance of the sum of $n$ of them is $\frac{n(N-n)}{N-1}$ times the individual variances. That reminds me of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3459280) I wrote not long ago.

Comment: OMG, yeah, this is a general result and comes from the symmetry of the remaining $N-1$ variables (after conditioning on the $N$th variable).  BTW your proof with integrals can be abbreviated into a one-liner: $Cov(X,Y) = E[\delta X \delta Y] = E_Y [E_X [\delta X \mid \delta Y] \delta Y] = E_Y[-\frac{\delta Y}{N-1} \delta Y] = -\frac{ Var(Y)}{N-1}$

Answer (score 4):

A symmetry-based proof that $E[n'] = n$.  Also possibly an approach for approximating, but not calculating exactly, $Var(n')$.

---

Imagine the original $N$ circle cards are in fact $N$ different colors, $c_1, ..., c_N$.  The same process is done to the deck, using as many square cards (of the same $N$ colors) as you need.

When the process is finished (i.e. no more circle cards), let random variable $X_j$ be the number of final cards of color $c_j$.  Clearly:

- $E[X_1] = E[X_2] = \dots = E[X_N]$ by symmetry,
- $X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_N = N$ by conservation of the total number of cards,
- $E[X_1] + E[X_2] + \dots + E[X_N] = N$ combining the above and using linearity of expectation,
- and therefore: $E[X_j] = 1$ for all $j$.

Now imagine you are partially colorblind and cannot distinguish between $c_1, ..., c_n$ and think of all of them as "red".  The final no. of "red" cards (to your eyes) will be $n' \equiv X_1 + \dots + X_n,$ and so we have $E[n'] = n$.  QED

---

Further thoughts on $Var(n')$:

Note that each of the $N$ colors can have at most $2$ final cards, i.e. $X_j \in \{0, 1, 2\}$.  It might be possible (but difficult/tedious) to calculate $Var(X_j)$, based on careful case analysis, e.g. $X_j = 2$ iff that $c_j$ circle card was picked as the first card of some round $t$, and, neither of the $2$ square cards of color $c_j$ added to the deck was subsequently replaced in rounds $> t$.

If we know $Var(X_j)$, then based on $n' \equiv X_1 + \dots + X_n,$ a decent approximation might be $Var(n') \approx n \times Var(X_j)$.  This would be exact equality if the $X_j$'s were independent, but of course they are actually dependent.  However, in the limit (or maybe more stringently: the large $n$ but much larger $N$ limit, i.e. $1 \ll n \ll N$), the approximation might be quite good.

The OP said numerically it seems $Var(n') \approx {3n(N-n) \over 4N}$.  This would be consistent with my thoughts above if $Var(X_j) = \frac34,$ in the $1 \ll n \ll N$ limit.

Comment: I just saw this. Your argument that $E[n'] = n$ is absolutely beautiful.

Comment: thanks.  i stole the idea from [Ned's answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3217023/show-that-probability-of-drawing-a-white-ball-second-time-from-an-urn-is-indepen)

Comment: @antkam: I used your result $E[X_j]=1$ in my answer to simplify the derivation of the variance.

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed true that $E[n'] = n$ for any $n \ge 1$.

The idea is to look at the random variable $c_R(t)+s_R(t)$ for each $t$, where $c_R(t)$ is the number of red circles and $s_R(t)$ is the number of red squares after $t$ processes/[plays of the game]. $c_B(t)$ and $s_B(t)$ are defined analogously.

By doing casework on whether a red circle or blue circle was chosen, we have $$E[c_R(t+1)+s_R(t+1)] = $$ $$\frac{c_R(t)}{c_R(t)+c_B(t)}\left[\frac{c_R(t)-1}{N}(c_R(t)-2+s_R(t)+2)+\frac{s_R(t)+1}{N}(c_R(t)-1+S_R(t)+1)+\frac{c_B(t)}{N}(c_R(t)-1+S_R(t)+2)+\frac{s_B(t)}{N}(c_R(t)-1+s_R(t)+2)\right]$$ $$+\frac{c_B(t)}{c_R(t)+c_B(t)}\left[\frac{c_B(t)-1}{N}(c_R(t)+s_R(t))+\frac{s_B(t)+1}{N}(c_R(t)+s_R(t))+\frac{c_R(t)}{N}(c_R(t)+s_R(t)-1)+\frac{s_R(t)}{N}(c_R(t)+s_R(t)-1)\right],$$ which after some computations, involving $c_R(t)+s_R(t)+c_B(t)+s_B(t) \equiv N$, gives $$E[c_R(t+1)+s_R(t+1)] = E[c_R(t)+s_R(t)](1-\frac{1}{N})+E\left[\frac{c_R(t)}{c_R(t)+c_B(t)}\right].$$ Similarly, $$E\left[\frac{c_R(t+1)}{c_R(t+1)+c_B(t+1)}\right] = $$ $$\frac{c_R(t)}{c_R(t)+c_B(t)}\left[\frac{c_R(t)-1}{N}(\frac{c_R(t)-2}{c_R(t)+c_B(t)-2})+\frac{c_B(t)}{N}(\frac{c_R(t)-1}{c_R(t)+c_B(t)-2})+\frac{s_R(t)+1+s_B(t)}{N}(\frac{c_R(t)-1}{c_R(t)+c_B(t)-1})\right]$$ $$+ \frac{c_B(t)}{c_R(t)+c_B(t)}\left[\frac{c_B(t)-1}{N}(\frac{c_R(t)}{c_R(t)+c_B(t)-2})+\frac{c_R(t)}{N}(\frac{c_R(t)-1}{c_R(t)+c_B(t)-2})+\frac{s_R(t)+s_B(t)+1}{N}(\frac{c_R(t)}{c_R(t)+c_B(t)-1})\right],$$ which after a very long computation using also $s_R(t)+s_B(t) \equiv N-c_R(t)-c_B(t)$ gives $$E\left[\frac{c_R(t+1)}{c_R(t+1)+c_B(t+1)}\right] = E\left[\frac{c_R(t)}{c_R(t)+c_B(t)}\right].$$ Since $E[\frac{c_R(0)}{c_R(0)+c_B(0)}] = \frac{n}{N}$, we see that $$E\left[\frac{c_R(t)}{c_R(t)+c_B(t)}\right] = \frac{n}{N}$$ for all $t \ge 0$. Therefore, $$E[c_R(t+1)+s_R(t+1)] = \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)E[c_R(t)+s_R(t)]+\frac{n}{N}.$$ Since $E[c_R(0)+s_R(0)] = n$, iteration/induction shows that $$E[c_R(t)+s_R(t)] = n$$ for all $t \ge 0$. In particular, we have $$E[n'] = n,$$ as desired.

Comment: Wow. The effort in this answer is great. Just the typesetting...

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a derivation of the variance.

Let $r(t)$ denote the proportion of circle cards left after time $t$, where a step takes time $\frac1N$. In each step, we remove one circle card, and then another circle card with probability $r$. Thus, in the limit $N\to\infty$, $r$ satisfies the differential equation

$$
r'=-(1+r)\;.
$$

The general solution is

$$
r=c\mathrm e^{-t}-1\;,
$$

and with $r(0)=1$ we have $c=2$, so

$$
r=2\mathrm e^{-t}-1\;,
$$

and thus

$$
t=-\log\frac{r+1}2\;.
$$

The process ends at $r=0$, and thus at $t=\log2$, so we expect it to take $N\log2$ steps.

Now focus on some particular circle card. It is replaced by a square card at some $r$ uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$. In the first half-step, it is replaced with probability $\frac1{rN}$, and in the second half-step it is replaced with probability $\frac1N$. Thus, conditional on the circle card being replaced at $r$, the probability that it’s replaced in the first half-step, and thus produces two square cards of its colour, is $\frac1{r+1}$. (The probability that the same card is selected in both half-steps is of order $\frac1N$ and thus negligible in the limit.)

If the circle card is replaced by $2$ square cards, there remain $N\left(\log2+\log\frac{r+1}2\right)=N\log(r+1)$ steps in which these $2$ square cards could be replaced by other square cards. The probability for neither of them to be replaced in any of these steps is

\begin{eqnarray}
\left(1-\frac2N\right)^{N\log(r+1)}
&\to_{n\to\infty}&
\exp(-2\log(r+1))
\\
&=&
(r+1)^{-2}\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Integrating over the uniform distribution with respect to $r$, we obtain the probability that the circle card leaves behind $2$ square cards (i.e. produces $2$ square cards, neither of which is replaced) as

$$
\int_0^1(r+1)^{-3}\mathrm dr=\frac38\;.
$$

As shown in [antkam’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3351149), the expected number of square cards that a circle card leaves behind is $1$, so the probability that it leaves behind $0$ cards must also be $\frac38$. For the change $D\in\{-1,0,1\}$ in the number of cards of this type, the variance is easily calculated as

$$\mathsf{Var}[D]=\mathsf E[D^2]-\mathsf E[D]^2=\mathsf E[D^2]=\mathsf P(D\ne0)\;,$$

so the variance in the number of cards left behind ($\mathsf{Var}[X_j]$) in antkam’s answer) is $\frac38+\frac38=\frac34$.

Your own answer shows that this implies the result for the total variance that you had obtained numerically. This is the somewhat hand-waving argument I gave for this before you posted your answer: With probability $\frac38+\frac38=\frac34$, the number of cards of the circle card’s colour changes by $\pm1$ with probability $\frac nN$ or $\frac{N-n}N$. The variance of the sum of these $\frac34N$ approximately independent Bernoulli variables is

$$
\frac34N\cdot\frac nN\left(1-\frac nN\right)=\frac{3n(N-n)}{4N}\;,
$$

in agreement with your numerical results.

I haven’t made any attempt to rigorously show that the errors all vanish in the limit $N\to\infty$, but this seems very plausible. For instance, the variance of the number of steps should be $O(\sqrt N)$, and $\left(1-\frac2N\right)^\sqrt N\to1$. The correlation among the Bernoulli trials should also go to zero, as it typically does in such scenarios.

Comment: That's a really nice proof for where the 3/8 probability comes from. I followed everything up to $3/8+3/8=3/4$, but I couldn't follow the rest of that paragraph. What are the Bernoulli variables? Also, have you seen my update 3? it looks like assuming independence would result in $n\text{Var}(X)=3n/4$ and we need the covariance terms of order $1/N$ to get the right result. What am I missing?

Comment: Let me clarify what is confusing from the last part to me: You are saying that there are $3N/4$ cards that change numbers and each one is with the probability of $n/N$ is of the first color and $1-n/N$ of the second color. But we are looking at the variance of the first color cards, so there are $3n/4$ first color cards that change numbers, $3n/8$ of them are $+1$ and $3n/8$ of them are $-1$. That gives the variance of $3n/4$ for change in number of first color cards.

Comment: @stochastic: I'd seen your update $3$, but I realize now that I hadn't read it carefully. I'm afraid my argument is slightly hand-waving. I'll have to think about it again to see how it can be done rigorously; I'll amend the answer if I come up with something. Note, though, that antkam also writes (without proof) that $\operatorname{Var} X_j=\frac34$ would lead to the observed result under the independence assumption.

Comment: I think antkam's response saying that the $3(−)/4$ is consistent with $\text{Var}(X)=3/4$ because setting $n$ to $1$ gives the $3/4$ results, not the other way around

Comment: +1 Lovely!!  You always take my simple ideas and turn them into something $10\times$ better!!  :)  My only "no proof" argument is simply that $Var(n') = n Var(X_j)$, and the "no proof" part comes from my _inability_ to justify the independence approximation -- I can only say if $N \gg n$ that should be OK...   Anyway, may I suggest you add a comment that $P(X_j = 0) = P(X_j = 2) = 3/8 \implies Var(X_j) = 3/4$?

Comment: @stochastic - I am simply saying if $N \gg n$ then the $(N-n)/N$ terms cancel.  There is no need to set $n=1$...  you just need $n \ll N$.

Comment: @antkam see my answer below (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3682238/491395) for the case where $n$ is not much smaller than $N$

Comment: @antkam: Thanks for your comments. I added the derivation of $\mathsf{Var}[X_j]=\frac34$ as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can model this as a discrete-time Markov chain with states $(\text{rc},\text{bc},\text{rs},\text{bs})\in S$, where $\text{rc}\ge 0$ is the number of red circles, etc., and $\text{rc}+\text{bc}+\text{rs}+\text{bs}=N$.  Given transition probabilities $p_{i,j}$, the absorption probabilities $\pi_{i,j} \ge 0$ of eventually ending up in state $j\in S$ starting from state $i\in S$ can be computed from the linear system:
\begin{align}
\pi_{i,j} &= \sum_{k\in S} p_{i,k} \pi_{k,j} &&\text{for all $i$ and $j$}\\
\pi_{i,i} &= 1 &&\text{if state $i$ has no circles}\\
\sum_{j \in S} \pi_{i,j} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}
Then $$P(n'|n) = \sum_{\substack{i \in S\\\text{$i$ has $n$ red circles}}} \sum_{\substack{j \in S\\\text{$j$ has $n'$ red squares}}} \pi_{i,j}.$$

For example, the values of $P(n'|n)$ for $N=8$ are as follows:

```
n\n'        0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
0   1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 
1   0.3603253 0.2793493 0.3603253 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 
2   0.1027300 0.2067804 0.3809791 0.2067804 0.1027300 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 
3   0.0196712 0.0874329 0.2453533 0.2950851 0.2453533 0.0874329 0.0196712 0.0000000 0.0000000 
4   0.0015393 0.0191598 0.1008081 0.2233022 0.3103814 0.2233022 0.1008081 0.0191598 0.0015393 
5   0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0196712 0.0874329 0.2453533 0.2950851 0.2453533 0.0874329 0.0196712 
6   0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1027300 0.2067804 0.3809791 0.2067804 0.1027300 
7   0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3603253 0.2793493 0.3603253 
8   0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000
```

From computations for small $N$, it does appear that $E(n'|n)=n$.