# Estimating the sum of subset of positive integers

Tags: probability, summation, integers

Suppose we have a sequence of n positive integers, each sampled from the pmf: p(c)
$${c_1, c_2, c_3,...,c_n}$$
$${c_i \in \mathbb{N}}$$

The sum of these integers is a known constant k 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i = k$$

Hence, the mean of the sequence is:

$$\bar{c} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i}{n} = \frac{k}{n}$$

Now, the first m numbers are summed to give x
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m} c_i = x$$

And this sum should be approximately equal to m lots of the mean

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m} c_i}{m} = \frac{x}{m} \approx \bar{c} \implies x \approx m\bar c$$

How can we estimate x (with a constant times this product), such that the estimate is both as close to the actual value as possible, but also below the actual with probability at least p
$$Pr(\alpha m \bar c<x)\geq p$$
$$\alpha \in [0, 1]$$

My first thought is that if alpha is 1, this will be an overestimate with p = 0.5

Only an approximate answer is required, no correct closed form answer is needed.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think that's going to be a complicated calculation, and it will involve lots of case work. It all depends on which combinations of the $c_i$ can add up to $k$ -- there might be just one such combination, or lots, and then you'd have to consider all permutations of each of those combinations -- sounds like a nightmare to me -- probably best left to a computer.

Comment: Thank you for commenting :) So it's all of the cis that sum to k. It sort of removes a degree of freedom I think

Comment: Yes. But you have the PMF of the $c_i$, and imposing the constraint that they add to $k$ turns that into potentially very complicated conditional probabilities for the sequence. For instance if the PMF has equal probabilities for $1$, $2$ and $3$, for $n=2$ and $k=4$ you have equal probabilities for the three sequences $1,3$ and $2,2$ and $3,1$; and if the PFM isn't uniform, those each have different probabilities, so you have to solve a partition problem for $k$ and obtain different probabilities for the different partitions. Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think that you're correct in that the way I've phrased it doesn't really work. What has actually happened is that we've sampled n time from p(c) and we happen to know the end result sum: k. Does this make the problem more possible? I'm also happy with approximations i.e. to the normal for large sums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're happy with a normal approximation, you can replace the $c_i$ by i.i.d. continuous Gaussian random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ determined from the PMF of the $c_i$. Then you're looking for the conditional probability distribution of the sum of the first $m$ of these variables, given that all $n$ of them sum to $k$. Let $S_j$ denote the sum of the first $j$ variables. Then

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{S_m}(S_m\mid S_n=k)
&=&\frac{f_{S_m,S_n}(S_m,k)}{f_{S_n}(k)}
\\
&=&
\frac{f_{S_m,S_{n-m}}(S_m,k-S_m)}{f_{S_n}(k)}
\\
&=&
\frac{f_{S_m}(S_m)f_{S_{n-m}}(k-S_m)}{f_{S_n}(k)}
\\
&=&
\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\frac n{m(n-m)}\exp\left(-\frac{(S_m-m\mu)^2}{2m\sigma^2}-\frac{(k-S_m-(n-m)\mu)^2}{2(n-m)\sigma^2}+\frac{(k-n\mu)^2}{2n\sigma^2}\right)
\\
&=&
\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma'^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(S_m-\mu')^2}{2\sigma'^2}\right),
\end{eqnarray*}

again a normal distribution, with mean

$$
\mu'=\frac mnk
$$

(as you expected) and variance

$$
\sigma'^2=\frac1{\frac1m+\frac1{n-m}}\sigma^2=\frac{m(n-m)}n\sigma^2\;,
$$

which is zero for $m=0$ or $m=n$ (since in these cases we know the sum to be $0$ and $k$, respectively) and takes its maximal value $\frac n4\sigma^2$ for $m=\frac n2$, i.e. half of the variance $\frac n2\sigma^2$ of the unconditional distribution of $S_{\frac n2}$.

Your constant $\alpha$ is then determined from

$$
P(S_m\gt\alpha\mu')=\frac12\left(1-\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{\alpha\mu'-\mu'}{\sigma'\sqrt2}\right)\right)=\frac12\left(1-\operatorname{erf}\left((\alpha-1)k\sqrt{\frac m{2n(n-m)}}\right)\right)\;;
$$

setting this equal to $p$ and solving for $\alpha$ yields $\alpha$ in terms of the [inverse error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Inverse_functions) $\operatorname{erf}^{-1}$:

$$
\alpha=1+\frac1k\sqrt{\frac{2n(n-m)}m}\operatorname{erf}^{-1}(1-2p)\;.
$$

As you expected, $\alpha=1$ for $p=\frac12$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your super detailed response! I was just wondering if you would be able to explain why we can say that the joint distribution of Sm, Sn at (Sm, k) is equal to the joint distribution of Sm, Sn-m at (Sm, k-Sm), (the answer to which might help me see then why Sm and Sn-m can be considered independent).

Comment: @CameronChandler: From your comment I realized that I was misusing the notation I introduced. $S_{n-m}$ was supposed to stand for the sum of the last, not the first, $n-m$ variables. (They have the same marginal distribution, but of course not the same joint distribution with $S_m$.) I've cleaned up the notation, and I hope it's clearer now. The step from $f_{S_m,S_n}$ to $f_{S_m,S_{[m+1,n]}}$ is a variable transformation from $S_n$ to $S_{[m+1,n]}$, with $\frac{\partial S_n}{\partial S_{[m+1,n]}}=\frac{\partial(S_m+S_{[m+1,n]})}{\partial S_{[m+1,n]}}=1$.